# ArrayList removes object from an other ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

So, I have this use case:

```
ArrayList<String> test1 = new ArrayList<String>();
test1.add("string1");
test1.add("string2");

ArrayList<String> test2 = test1;
test2.remove(0);
System.out.println(test1.get(0)); // Expect to see "string1"
```

The first ArrayList `test1`, has two String elements. Then I make a new (?) ArrayList, `test2`, which is the same as `test1`. When I remove the first element from `test2` (which is "string1") and then try to display the first element from `test1`, it returns "string2"... also there the first element "string1" is removed somehow.

How is that possible?

Comment: you're using the same instance of the arraylist in both variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then I make a new (?) ArrayList, test2, which is the same as test1.

No you haven't. You have just pointed your arraylist 2 to arraylist 1.

You can either use a Shallow constructor of list or use addAll method.

```
List<String> test2 = new ArrayList<String>();
test2.addAll(test1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the reference of `test1` to `test2`. This means, that both the `ArrayList` refer to the same instance,

Therefore,  methods called on one, will virtually reflect in the other one too, as they refer to the same object.

To achieve what you want, do

```
List<String> test2 = new ArrayList<>(test1);
```

This copies the contents of the `test1` to `test2`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new *ArrayList* with the same elements as test1

```
ArrayList<String> test2 = new ArrayList<>(test1)
```

Comment: Why not just `ArrayList<String> test2 = new ArrayList<>(test1)`?  What do you think `Arrays.asList()` adds to the picture?

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList<String> test1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    test1.add("string1");
    test1.add("string2");

    ArrayList<String> test2 = test1;
    test2.remove(0);
    System.out.println(test1.get(0)); // Expect to see "string1"

    ArrayList<String> test3 = new ArrayList<>();
```

Upon running the code in debug you can see that the reference of test1 and test2 is pointing to the same location. That is because you are not copying the values but assigning the same reference to the other list. Notice that the reference of test3 is different than the other 2.

In order to just copy the values you can use

```
test2 = new ArrayList<Object>(test1);
```

Please find the image attached below to view the reference value.

[Result of running the code stated above in debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoILz.png)